# Nesting calls to static methods

Tags: java

I want to do something like below, but it does not work. My objective is to be able to nest function calls to static helper classes to get more brevity.

```
public class StaticHelper {
    public static Class<StaticHelper> doSomthing() {
        System.out.println("I just did something !!");
        return StaticHelper.class;
    }

    public static Class<StaticHelper> doSomthingElse() {
        System.out.println("I just did something else !!");
        return StaticHelper.class;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Does not compiles 
        StaticHelper.doSomthing().doSomthingElse();
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If so a simple example as above will be very helpful.

Comment: Java is statically typed. What you are trying to do makes no sense. Either call static methods directly, or call instance methods using interfaces.

Comment: May I ask: why do you want to do that? **static** should be seen as awkward thing within object-oriented programming; and it has a lot of disadvantages; for example it can make writing unit-tests very hard  - so why do you want to use static in such a way?

Comment: Please note , statics are bad if you have static members also referred to as GLOBAL STATE. If static classes do not contain GLOBAL STATE, they are no pain to be unit tested.

Comment: The reason I want something like above is because I do not want to create new object instanaces pure helper functions (like validate input args much like PreCondition in guava). At the same time I would not want to make many separate calls to the class for each validation that I do. I want a single (nested) call that allows me to do all my validation.

Comment: Can you give a real example then? The solution may depend on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, but using [static imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) is.

```
public class StaticHelper {
    public static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I just did something !!");
    }

    public static void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println("I just did something else !!");
    }
}
```

in another class:

```
import static StaticHelper.*;

class Other {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomething(); // calls static methods from StaticHelper
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

or - if the methods are logically connected - you can have one static factory method and the rest are instance methods:

```
public class StaticHelper {
    public static void beginDoingSomething() {
        // static factory method - you can pass parameters to it if needed
        System.out.println("I just did something !!");
        return new StaticHelper();
        // if needed, initialize the instance with the parameters
    }

    public StaticHelper andDoSomethingElse() {
        // instance method
        // can use the instance parameters (passed to the constructor in the static factory method)
        // or use parameters passed to this method 
        System.out.println("I just did something else !!");
        return this;
        // returns this for chaining
    }
}
```

in another class:

```
import static StaticHelper.*;

class Other {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomething().andDoSomethingElse().andDoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

If you name the methods nicely, you can form a sentence:

```
validate(object).checkEmail().checkName().checkTelephoneStartsWith("+11");
```

where `validate(object)` is a static factory method constructing a new validator instance for the given `object`.

Comment: Yes, I know .. but is there way to avoid all those multiple statements per call ?

Comment: Can you accept the answer, please? (the big tick to the left)

Comment: I would have ticked but there is an issue with the solution. The solution mandates exact ordering of function calls, what if I want to call doSomethingElse first and then doSomething , cant do that without explicitly instantiating StaticHelper.

Comment: A helper class encapsulates related set of processing logic and must be stateless to enable independent invocations of its helper functions in any order sequentially or in parallel.

Comment: Well, you've got to post your real problem then, no way to come up with a one-size-fits-all solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this.

```
public class StaticHelper {
    private final static StaticHelper INSTANCE = new StaticHelper();

    public static StaticHelper doSomthing(){
        System.out.println("I just did something !!");
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static StaticHelper doSomthingElse(){
        System.out.println("I just did something else !!");
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticHelper.doSomthing().doSomthingElse();
    }
}
```

or another way

```
public class StaticHelper {
    public static SomeClass doSomthing(){
        return new SomeClass().doSomthing();
    }

    public static SomeClass doSomthingElse(){
        return new SomeClass().doSomthingElse();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticHelper.doSomthing().doSomthingElse();
    }

    private static class SomeClass {

        public SomeClass doSomthing(){
            System.out.println("I just did something !!");
            return this;
        }

        public SomeClass doSomthingElse(){
            System.out.println("I just did something else !!");
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No , Static Singletons are EVIL. Anything other way ?? But sure can do if class is state less.

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: I think Adam Michalik does pretty much the same but some how I find it much more readable. I liked your previous example more. It was much more simple and readable. With You next example I kind of got puzzelled thinking how many instances of which objects were getting created.

Comment: Everything depends on what you want do.

Comment: Agree, but there is something called as general guidelines , which is why although we write many K lines of code , we still strive for Readability, Maintainability and Testability. Any code that is not RMT is not good :)

Comment: Right, but I think this code from second part is readably, testable, etc. In my opinion, if you need some code with one static method to create a instance of object (like typical builder), you can do that. But sometime, it easy to use many static method to create the instance (like javax.ws.rs.core.Response) it also correct. Everything depends what you needed :).